# Get position of selected elements, not index of element in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div>
  <h3>Heading one</h3>
  <h3>Heading two</h3>
  <h4>heading caption</h4>
  <h3>Heading three</h3>
</div>​
```

I want to get the position of the element within the jQuery selection, rather than it's index in the DOM.

At the moment, if I `alert($("h3").eq(2).index());` I'll get '3' - I want '2'.

http://jsfiddle.net/4QmEF/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... the `.eq(2)` is zero-based so it is selecting the `<h3>Heading three</h3>`. What makes that the 2nd element in the jQuery selection?

Comment: @Cecchi - Probably wasn't the best example, but there is a `h4` hidden in there, muddying the straight `index()` call, as it checks the index within the parent, which has one extra element than the selector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pass your index() a selector:

```
alert($("h3").eq(2).index("h3"));
```

Comment: boom! thanks. I knew there was a quick and easy way ! - gotta wait 10mins to accept though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
   <h3>Heading one</h3>
   <h3>Heading two</h3>
   <h4>heading caption</h4>
   <h3>Heading three</h3>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("div").children().each(function(){  
        $(this).click(function(){
            alert($(this).context.innerHTML);
        });  
    });
});
</script>`
```

Comment: Get the all child of the div position by clicking on that particular code