# index of element in regard to elements of same type?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get position of selected elements, not index of element in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423357/get-position-of-selected-elements-not-index-of-element-in-dom)

Using JQuery, what is the optimal way to get the index of an element in regard to other siblings of the same type, disregarding siblings of other types?

```
<span/>
<span/>
<div/>
<span/> <-- index of this guy in regard to just span tags? (answer: 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Example on how to do this with jQuery by comparing element references:

jquery solution:

```
var tested_element = document.getElementById('tested');
alert( $('#test').children('span').index(tested_element) ); // result: 2
```

javascript solution:

```
var tested = document.getElementById('tested');
var container = document.getElementById('test');
var node = container.childNodes[0];
var position = 0;
while ( node && node != tested ){
    if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.tagName == 'SPAN') {
        position++;
    }
    node = node.nextSibling;
}
if (!node) {
    position = -1; // element not found
}
alert(position);
```

tested html:

```
<div id="test">
    <span>A</span>
    <span>B</span>
    <div>C</div>
    <span id="tested">D</span>
    <span>E</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The looping is overkill, there's a jquery method called `index`.  If you're going to this extent and using `getElementById`, why bother with jquery?

Comment: @JamesMontagne Thanks James for the info, didn't know it. Updated the algorythm to be more effective.